# UserControl TextBox get set Property

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, get, set

I am getting the following error:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
 occurred in ciscontrols.dll
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
private int Dval;
public int DecPlaces
{
    get { return Dval; }
    set
    {
        DecPlaces = value;
        if (value < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("decplaces", "decimal places minimum value should be 2.");
        }
        else this.Dval = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `DecPlaces = value` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment in the code -

```
private int Dval;
    public int DecPlaces
    {
        get { return Dval; }
        set
        {
            //DecPlaces = value;  **** This is calling set method again, hence the exception. Just comment this line

            if (value < 2)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("decplaces", "decimal places minimum value should be 2.");
            }
            else this.Dval = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the Set Property Inifinite Manner

```
  DecPlaces = value;
```

use some lcoal variable to do this.

```
int m= value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
DecPlaces = value;
```

You're self-referencing. You keep making a call to your setter. Just remove that line and you should be good.